# magento 1.9 library guzzlehttp

Tags: php, magento, autoloader, guzzle

I have a problem with Magento 1.9 when I attach the guzzlehttp library to a call:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client ();
return Mage::log($this->client);
```

I am getting:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'GuzzleHttp\Client.php' for inclusion (include_path='...') in /../lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.x does not use composer for managing its dependancies.

You'll have to manually include composer autoload file from your code – `include 'vendor/autoload.php'`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed to include the autoload file for the GuzzleHttp, GuzzleHttp uses composer to autoload its classes. if using multiple libraries with comoser you should dump-autoload as:

```
->composer dump-autoload
```